# Passing listview array strings to viewtext in another activity

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-intent, textview

I have a listview activity that displays an array (ml_main) from my custom class (ml_lists) and adapter (ml_my_adapter). The array is added to via another activity. I have a 3rd activity that I want to display the item and subitem in textviews when the appropriate listitem is selected. Its this last part that I am struggling with, my intent opens the 3rd activity but the textviews are empty (dont even appear), any help really appreciated, code below...

```
package com.example.adam.mylists;

public class ml_lists {


    // Store the name of the item
    private String mItem;
    // Store the name of the subitem
    private String mSubItem;

    // Constructor that is used to create an instance of the list_my_list  object
    public ml_lists(String mItem, String mSubItem) {

        this.mItem = mItem;
        this.mSubItem = mSubItem;
    }

    public String getmItem() {
        return mItem;
    }

    public void setmItem(String mItem) {
        this.mItem = mItem;
    }

    public String getmSubItem() {
        return mSubItem;
    }

    public void setmSubItem(String mSubItem) {
        this.mSubItem = mSubItem;
    }
}


package com.example.adam.mylists;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/*The code is now stable to generate a list which is predefined, now need to amend so that
it is populated via user input*/

public class ml_main extends AppCompatActivity {


    String item;
    String subitem;
    ArrayList<ml_lists> userlist = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView listView;
    private ml_my_adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ml_main);

        final Context context = getApplicationContext();
        final FloatingActionButton addnewitem = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview_list);
        userlist.add(new ml_lists("Item 1 example", "Sub item 1 example"));
        mAdapter = new ml_my_adapter(this, userlist);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        addnewitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent launchactivity = new Intent(context, ml_create_new_item_screen.class);
                startActivityForResult(launchactivity, 1);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
            }
        });

        /*BELOW CODE TO SELECT ITEM FROM LISTVIEW AND OPEN IT BACK UP IN THE CREATE ITEM ACT*/
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                /*intent used to open selected activity into editor*/
                Intent edititem = new Intent(context, ml_edit_existing_item_screen.class);
                edititem.putExtra("item",item);
                edititem.putExtra("subitem",subitem);
                startActivity(edititem);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                item = data.getStringExtra("tempitem");
                subitem = data.getStringExtra("tempsubitem");
                userlist.add(new ml_lists(item, subitem));
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast replacewithcode = Toast.makeText(ml_main.this, "replace with code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                replacewithcode.show();
            }
        }
    }
}




package com.example.adam.mylists;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/*Created by Adam Garnham*/

public class ml_my_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<ml_lists> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<ml_lists> mList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ml_my_adapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes ArrayList<ml_lists> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
        mContext = context;
        mList = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if (listItem == null)
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        ml_lists currentItem = mList.get(position);

        TextView mItem = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_item);
        mItem.setText(currentItem.getmItem());

        TextView mSubItem = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_subitem);
        mSubItem.setText(currentItem.getmSubItem());

        return listItem;
    }
}

package com.example.adam.mylists;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Adam on 02/01/2018.
 */

public class ml_edit_existing_item_screen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_existing_item_screen);


        Intent edititem = getIntent();
        String item = edititem.getStringExtra("item");
        String subitem = edititem.getStringExtra("subitem");

        TextView itemtextview = findViewById(R.id.itemtextview);
        TextView subitemtextview = findViewById(R.id.subitemtextview);

        itemtextview.setText(item);
        subitemtextview.setText(subitem);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not assigning values to "item" and "subitem" in your on click listener. They are empty. You can fetch the values of current selected item by passing the selected position to userlist.

Most probably you can do something likes this.

```
ml_lists selectedItem=userlist.get(i);
item=selectedItem.getmItem();
subItem=selectedItem.getmSubItem();
```